# Add star icon on candlestick Google Chart

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, graphics, google-visualization

I'm trying to add a star icon to candlestick chart with Google Charts api, but I'm having difficulty. If anyone can help me:

I saw it working on this google page: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/points
https://i.stack.imgur.com/blkeK.png

As much as I add css and define the column type, it doesn't work.

Below is my code, but this is the test link in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wd4egpo1/

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'n1', 'n2', 'n3', 'n4', {label:'point', role:'style', type:'string'}],
      ['Mon', 20, 28, 38, 45, undefined],
      ['Tue', 31, 38, 55, 66, undefined],
      ['Wed', 50, 55, 77, 80, undefined],
      ['Thu', 77, 77, 66, 50, 'point { size: 18; shape-type: star; fill-color: #a52714; }'],
      ['Fri', 68, 66, 22, 15, undefined]
      // Treat first row as data as well.
    ], false);

    var options = {
      legend:'none'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.CandlestickChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [example](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/points) that you saw was only applicable to `line` and `scatter` charts which contains points. Customization of these points were provided in that docs. `Candlestick` chart does not have any points thats why its not working. You can still provide styling of your charts at data level just by providing the style object as done below:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'n1', 'n2', 'n3', 'n4', {'type': 'string', 'role': 'style'}],
      ['Mon', 20, 28, 38, 45, null],
      ['Tue', 31, 38, 55, 66, null],
      ['Wed', 50, 55, 77, 80, null],
      ['Thu', 77, 77, 66, 50, '{ size: 18; shape-type: star; fill-color: #a52714; }'],
      ['Fri', 68, 66, 22, 15, null]
      // Treat first row as data as well.
    ], false);
```

In the above, the shape will not be applied but the fill color can be applied. If you want more options, specific to changing the color of your chart then you should try the following in `options`:

```
var options = {
          legend: 'none',
          bar: { groupWidth: '100%' }, // Remove space between bars.
          candlestick: {
            fallingColor: { strokeWidth: 0, fill: '#a52714' }, // red
            risingColor: { strokeWidth: 0, fill: '#0f9d58' }   // green
          }
        };
```

Also refer the docs for [CandlestickChart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/candlestickchart#configuration-options) which has more options and a sample [example](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/candlestickchart#waterfall-charts) where color is changed.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply @wehab . I still need to insert some kind of point/icon in at specific points on the chart. Any idea how I can do it?